# How long is too long for a personal statement for undergrad research application?

Tags: application, research-undergraduate, statement-of-purpose

Many REUs (Research Experiences for Undergraduates) require a personal statement or related essay as part of the application. I am wondering, how long is too long? My essay is right now 1000 words (but it could be ~1300), and my worry is that the people reading it will lose interest in an essay that long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that the personal and research statements for the [NSF Graduate Research Fellowship](https://www.nsfgrfp.org) are restricted to two pages each. So if you're writing more than that for a REU, you're probably writing too much.

Comment: Double spaced or single spaced?

Comment: The NSF applications are single-spaced.

Comment: Also, what if the program "only" requires one essay? Does that mean that they are willing to read 3-4 pages of my personal info AND my research interests?

Comment: If they only want one essay, two pages (ca. 1000 words) is probably reasonable.